# gensim can not be imported because ImportError: No module named queue?

Tags: python-2.7, queue, gensim

I need to do some experiments on text files using gensim on mac Yosemite.

I've already installed `numpy` and `scipy` but when I want to import `gensim`.

I'm facing this error:

```
from six.moves.queue import Queue as _Queue
ImportError: No module named queue
```

I upgraded `numpy` and `scipy` to latest version and Python is 2.7.10.

I read that the problem may be solved by hacking the `gensim` code to `from Queue import Queue as _Queue` but I don't know how!

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the website `genesis` should work with python 2.7, however, I still think you can simply solve your issue by using it with python 3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was solved for me when I modified the gensim code based on these instructions [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/408/commits/21e9c1e8d9b272b89edcabe17fb6c6e1d53ae2a9)

(the discussion is [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/408))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be caused to extra versions of `numpy`, `scipy`, and `six` installed on my machine.  Python was not importing the proper versions.

I used these commands to see which installation paths Python was pointing to:

`python -c 'import os,numpy;print(numpy.\__file__)'`

`python -c 'import os,six;print(six.\__file__)'`

I deleted "rogue" versions of these modules and made sure the versions located in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/... were the ones python referred to when using import.  This folder had the most up to date version of  This may be different in your case depending on your os and preferred methods of installing packages.

If you are still facing errors there may be other libraries causing issues due to improper imports. Check to see what other dependencies gensim has to further diagnose the issue.

This blog post (https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html) helped me understand this process better.